# Why does my lua script print both values?

Tags: lua

first of all, this is my first time coding in Lua, let alone coding at all.

I'm testing out lua for making some mods, and I can't really figure out what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get my script to say 2 different things with 2 different values, but lua keeps printing BOTH values.

Here is my code:

```
sword = unequipped 
if sword == equipped then
print("This feels quite heavy")end 
if sword == unequipped then 
print("I feel unstoppable")
end
```

When I run the script, it prints out both values, so in terminal, it says;

```
 This feels quite heavy
 I feel unstoppable
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is you haven't defined `unequipped` or `equipped` so they are both `nil` so `sword` is equal to both of them.

In general when you have a problem like this, try using the interactive interpreter.  e.g.

```
bash-3.2$ lua
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> sword = unequipped
> print(sword)
nil
> print(equipped)
nil
> print(sword == equipped)
true
```

Comment: and then it should work? can i also do that in my script?

Comment: Running the interpreter interactively will help you figure out what is going on but it is still up to you to make it work.  In this particular case you probably want to either a) assign `unequipped` and `equipped` to different values before assigning `sword` or possibly b) switch to using string literals with quotes, e.g. `sword = "unequipped"`, `if sword == "equipped"` and so on but there are many things you could do. What approach you take is ultimately up to you.

Comment: You're welcome.  One small thing: this question has nothing to do with [tag:emacs] so you might want to remove that tag.